# 'RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h' file not found after adding firebase crashlytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

My problem started when I wanted to add the module @react-native-firebase/crashlytics. I had [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374899/add-crashlytics-to-react-native-project-throws-an-error/74375028#74375028) when I tried to add the module, so I hat to execute the following commands

```
rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
```

and I had to add the following line to the pod file

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

and changed ios 12.1 to:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

With this changes I was able to add crashlytics to the projects, but the app is not running anymore, I get a build error in xCode

```
RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h' file not found
```

Comment: Do you get this error if you remove Crashlytics but maintaining the current configuration? It would be interesting to see if this is related to the Crashlytics SDK or caused by a different library being used.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing use_frameworks from the Podfile and using older version of firebasemodule

```
    @react-native-firebase/app": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "14.12.0",
```